# Using os.path.join on Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: python, operating-system

Apparently running `os.path.join` on Ubuntu on Windows 10 gives the path in the Windows OS (with the backslash separator). Is there a way to override that (other than, of course, booting from an *actual* Ubuntu machine?)

I'm trying to use sqlalchemy on an sqlite file, and `create_engine('sqlite:///{0}'.format(db_filepath))` is giving me headaches.

Comment: If you executed the Windows version of Python from within WSL that can happen.

Comment: I haven't installed python 3 on WSL...so I'm guessing it's built-in? Or is it calling the Windows version of python 3 that I've installed?

Comment: Maybe you can use the pathlib module, but I can't try it. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: Try `import os` and/or `import sys` and check the values of `os.platform` and/or `sys.executable`, and also see that `os.path` is actually `posixpath` and not `ntpath`.

Comment: Ah got it working finally. I installed the virtualenv on Python 3 by specifying Python3 specifically and for some weird reason, it now works. Apparently, it *was* running the Windows version of Python from within WSL.

Comment: You may consider putting that comment as a self answer to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on metatoaster's suggestion, I reinstalled a virtualenv (via `virtualenvwrapper`) on Python 3 on WSL using

```
mkvirtualenv envname --python=`which python3`
```

So when I run python3, everything now works. Apparently, I was calling the Windows version of Python.